# "TypeError: etherscan.apiKey.trim is not a function" with multiple API keys

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, contract-verification

greeting

the next link continue part about Multiple API keys and alternative block explorers

https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/tree/master/packages/hardhat-etherscan#multiple-api-keys-and-alternative-block-explorers

when try apply that on my code face  "TypeError: etherscan.apiKey.trim is not a function"

1- I add values of api key as environments variables.

2- I use @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan plugin for verifying process.

3- I use next command to verify the smart contract:

```
npx hardhat verify --network matic contract address
```

that's the code before add multi api key(work correct, without any problem for rinkepy and polygon)

```
module.exports = {
defaultNetwork: "matic",
networks: {

    rinkeby: {
        url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
        accounts: {
            mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
        },
        saveDeployments: true,
    },

    matic: {
        url: Mumbai_RPC_URL,
        accounts: {
            mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
        },
        saveDeployments: true,
    },
},

etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
},
```

next code after add multi api key can help me to know what wrong in it

```
module.exports = {
defaultNetwork: "matic",
networks: {

    rinkeby: {
        url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
        accounts: {
            mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
        },
        saveDeployments: true,
    },

    matic: {
        url: Mumbai_RPC_URL,
        accounts: {
            mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
        },
        saveDeployments: true,
    },
},

etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
              rinkeby: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
              polygonMumbai: POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY,
    }
},
```

Comment: The code you pasted is not the code failing you need ot check where are you trimming the apiKey as it says on the error

Comment: i add values of api key as environments variables, so there's no trim happend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this same error (on rinkeby network).
Fixed by removing the @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan package, then reinstalling it:

```
npm remove @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan
```

then

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The use of multiple API keys and alternative block explorers is only available since @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan version 3.0.0. That's why the suggestion made by "panda" works (install latest version).

ps-i would like to add only a comment by not possible for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1117#issuecomment-779213915 will help you as it solved this for me.

If not, you may try to set `mumbai` as default network and just leave the signle `apiKey`..anyway it seems you have not defined the polygon testnet connection details at all.

Comment: thanks a lot. matic is the polygon testnet, and i add the details as environments variables.
i already finish work with rinkeby and i will only need one api (polygon api) so i will not face same problem again. just try understand what wrong to avoid it in the feature.